# Is there a specification of script execution order when using iframes?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

It's fairly well known and understood that browsers will execute `<script>` elements in the order presented within the source of a page (barring `defer` and `async` etc).  What I've not been able to establish is if there is a specification that guarantees an order across `<iframe>` elements also.

If my main page contains:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="a.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <iframe src="inner.html" />
    <!-- ... -->
  </body>
</html>
```

With inner.html being:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="b.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- ... -->
  </body>
</html>
```

Is it *defined in a specification* that `a.js` will execute before `b.js`?

What if the main page looks like this:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="a.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <iframe src="inner.html" />
    <!-- ... -->
    <script src="c.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

What is the guaranteed order of execution here, if there is one?  Say `a.js` takes a long time to load - it's guaranteed to still run before `c.js`.  But what if `inner.html` and all it's resources (including `b.js`) have loaded before `a.js` - is there anything in the HTML spec that says `b.js` *will not* run before `a.js`?  If it all loads normally in a timely manner, is it defined in a spec somewhere as to whether `b.js` should execute before or after `c.js`?

The best I've managed to find so far from [the `<iframe>` spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/embedded-content.html#the-iframe-element:document-7) is:

> When a Document in an iframe is marked as completely loaded, the user agent must run the iframe load event steps in parallel.

However that seems to just say (when you dig into the "iframe load event steps") that the `load` event will be dispatched in and amongst other things running on the main page, but doesn't say when the inner page will be parsed and content loaded and (critically) when scripts are to be run within it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [specification](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/scripting.html#the-script-element) of the `script` element seems clear to me:

> There are three possible modes that can be selected using these attributes. If the `async` attribute is present, then the `script` will be executed as soon as it is available, but without blocking further parsing of the page. If the `async` attribute is not present but the `defer` attribute is present, then the `script` is executed when the page has finished parsing. **If neither attribute is present, then the `script` is fetched and executed immediately, before the user agent continues parsing the page.**

(Emphasis added.)

You ask:

> Say `a.js` takes a long time to load - it's guaranteed to still run before `c.js`. But what if `inner.html` and all it's resources (including `b.js`) have loaded before `a.js` - is there anything in the HTML spec that says `b.js` will not run before `a.js`?

Yes, the section I quoted above implies that `b.js` won't run before `a.js`. Per the specification, *parsing will stop* while `a.js` is fetched and executed. Processing of the `iframe` is not going to happen until after parsing resume, which means that `b.js` cannot run before `a.js`.

`c.js` could execute before `b.js`. There is no single neat paragraph that I can point at to justify this though. The explanation for this is spread throughout the specification. What happens is that the `iframe` triggers a navigation to the URL passed in the `src`. (In the spec this is expressed as "Navigate the element's child browsing context to `url`." Navigation is described [here](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/browsers.html#navigate).) This navigation event will cause a fetch to happen. (Fetch is described [here](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/infrastructure.html#fetch).) And fetches are executed in parallel by default. A `script` element with `src` also fetches some data but (without `async` or `defer`) it *also* stops the parsing while the fetching happens.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense.  What would you read into the order of `b.js` vs `c.js`?

Comment: Thanks, had a chance to re-read this now.  Sounds like `a->b` is guaranteed, but `b->c/c->b` is potentially a race condition/implementation detail.

Answer (score -2):

Talking specific to chrome, each of the frames loaded inside the browser use the same render process but they have different contexts. (please check CEF3 underlying framework).Considering this fact only single process is responsible for both iframe and mainframe execution and following code, I think i can safely say that main frame loads first and then subframes are loaded. (can check callbacks we get from CEF3 on CEF test apps to confirm this again).
i.e. a.js and c.js are executed first and then b.js.

Parent HTML code:

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.abc = "ramesh";
</script>
</head>
<body>

<iframe id="iframeId" src="testiframe.html">
</iframe>

<script type = "text/javascript">
for (i=0;i<10000;i++) 
{
    console.log("something");
}
var p = document.getElementById("iframeId");
console.log(p.contentWindow.testValue);
</script>
</body>
```

iframe code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.testValue = "pqrs";
console.log("xyz");
</script>
<body>
</body>
```

iframe code should take far less time than the for loop I am printing. But this code always prints consoles from main frame first and if i try to access testValue from iframe's contentWindow, it says undefined (this is done to check its not about console log printing order and actual javascript execution order).

Hope this helps. Let me know if I missed any detail while coming to this conclusion.

Comment: That may be the current behaviour, but is there anything to say it wouldn't change in the future (or indeed currently, if it's actually a race condition that isn't actually defined either way in the spec - what if `a.js` or `c.js` take ages to download from the server, perhaps `b.js` would run first then?), or be different in other browsers?  Again, I'm looking for an actual spec one way or the other.  At the moment, I'm led to believe it's a race and there are no guarantees.

Comment: yes I dont think anybody can assure about the change in the future for example: taken from http://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/process-models
Subframes are currently rendered in the same process as their parent page. Although cross-site subframes do not have script access to their parents and could safely be rendered in a separate process, Chromium does not yet render them in their own processes. Similar to the first caveat, this means that pages from different sites may be rendered in the same process. This will likely change in future versions of Chromium.

Comment: and resource loading is definitely browser specific (downloading js that takes long) But as per my understanding, rendering goes in the order that we provide(even if one js is taking too much time, if all the next js files are dependent on that, it is bound to wait for it) . I dont think there is a concrete guideline provided by browsers. More than spec it is better to understand how page is loaded/rendered/resources are handled which would give better picture i hope.

Comment: On the contrary, it should be irrelevant how pages are loaded and rendered in each individual browser, as each of those should be conforming to the same spec.  If the spec is woolly, each one is open to do it how it wants, and could be different from each other, and may change in the future.  On the other hand, if the spec mandates the order of script execution, they should all adhere to it, no matter how they go about loading/rendering resources.  At the moment from my reading I'm under the impression that this is a woolly area, so can't be depended on either way.